# FK de la misma tabla, mostrar datos

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me podría ayudar con la sentencia?

Quisiera que el `nIdePadre = '1'` muestre en otra columna la descripción de `nIdeArea = '1'`, y más o menos que quede así:

```
nIdarea  --- nIdePadre --- nIdeEmpresa --- VDescripcion -- vDescrPadre
  1                                         PepitoPerez...
  2            1                            Tienda Arequipa     Pepito Perez 
  3            1                            Tienda Olivos       Pepito Perez
```

¿Es posible esto?

El `nIdePadre` y `nIdeEmpresa` son FK del `nIdarea`.

Comment: ¿De qué tabla es `vDescrPadre`? No se entiende lo que quieres hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, puedes hacer un `JOIN` a la misma tabla...

Algo así:

```
select A.nIdarea, A.nIdePadre, A.nIdeEmpresa, A.vDescripcion, B.vDescripcion as vDescrPadre
from NombreTabla A join NombreTabla B on A.nIdePadre = B.nIdarea
```

donde `NombreTabla` es el nombre de tu tabla (que no dijiste cuál es...).

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tendría esto? No lo entiendo...

Comment: @A.Cedano Obtener la descripción de la _foreign key_...

Comment: @A.Cedano obtener las relaciones en una tabla padre hijo que son la misma tabla (para empleados y jefaturas suele usarse mucho)